# Configuring LaTeXila to build with PdfLaTex and Biber

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber, editors, undefined

How do I go about setting up LaTeXila to be able to run Biber, and how do I set up the PdfLaTeX/Biber/PdfLaTeX(x2)/View Pdf cycle in LaTeXila?

I tried to set up LaTeXila adapting the solutions I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations) on stackexchange, and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X19dq_ohJpY) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvS52511oQ) on youtube, but I did not manage to. Following these instructions, I  only managed to set up TexMaker and TexStudio to build my thesis with PdfLateX and biber, but the GUI of both editors has problems with scaling and hi-dpi monitors on linux.

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/LaTeXila mentions that LaTeXila uses `latexmk` by default. This tool should be able to run Biber for your automatically, you would not have to change anything. Of course if you have changed the settings already, you might have to revert back.

Answer (score 1):

[LaTeXila](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/LaTeXila) now known as [GNOME LaTeX](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/GNOME-LaTeX) uses [`latexmk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) as a build tool.

`latexmk` can automatically figure out which tools and programmes to run and will automatically run Biber for you if and when required.

If you must set up a job for Biber on its own, follow the steps in [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446200/35864).